# How to list vms that was started from hyperkit?

Tags: hyperkit

How to list vms that was started from hyperkit?
hyperkit help is only below:

```
hyperkit -h                                                                                                                             11:25:45
Usage: hyperkit [-behuwxMACHPWY] [-c vcpus] [-F <pidfile>] [-g <gdb port>] [-l <lpc>]
                [-m mem] [-p vcpu:hostcpu] [-s <pci>] [-U uuid] -f <fw>
       -A: create ACPI tables
       -c: # cpus (default 1)
       -C: include guest memory in core file
       -e: exit on unhandled I/O access
       -f: firmware
       -F: pidfile
       -g: gdb port
       -h: help
       -H: vmexit from the guest on hlt
       -l: LPC device configuration. Ex: -l com1,stdio -l com2,autopty -l com2,/dev/myownpty
       -m: memory size in MB, may be suffixed with one of K, M, G or T
       -M: print MAC address and exit if using vmnet
       -P: vmexit from the guest on pause
       -s: <slot,driver,configinfo> PCI slot config
       -u: RTC keeps UTC time
       -U: uuid
       -v: show build version
       -w: ignore unimplemented MSRs
       -W: force virtio to use single-vector MSI
       -x: local apic is in x2APIC mode
       -Y: disable MPtable generation
```

I can't understand how to list vms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since hyperkit is just "[a toolkit for embedding hypervisor capabilities in your application.](https://github.com/moby/hyperkit)" it doesn't provide tools to manage the virtual machines directly.

The way you have to see all the virtual machines is:

```
$ ps -Af | grep hyperkit
0 35982     1   0  2:50PM ttys000    3:27.65 /usr/local/bin/hyperkit -A -u -F /Users/youruser/.minikube/machines/minikube/hyperkit.pid -c 2 -m 4000M -s 0:0,hostbridge -s 31,lpc -s 1:0,virtio-net -U 39c5590a-cdac-11ea-b300-acde48001122 -s 2:0,virtio-blk,/Users/youruser/.minikube/machines/minikube/minikube.rawdisk -s 3,ahci-cd,/Users/youruser/.minikube/machines/minikube/boot2docker.iso -s 4,virtio-rnd -l com1,autopty=/Users/youruser/.minikube/machines/minikube/tty,log=/Users/youruser/.minikube/machines/minikube/console-ring -f kexec,/Users/youruser/.minikube/machines/minikube/bzimage,/Users/youruser/.minikube/machines/minikube/initrd,earlyprintk=serial loglevel=3 console=ttyS0 console=tty0 noembed nomodeset norestore waitusb=10 systemd.legacy_systemd_cgroup_controller=yes random.trust_cpu=on hw_rng_model=virtio base host=minikube
```

in case you'll see in the previous command the "-l" flag with a tty available like this "`-l com1,autopty=/Users/youruser/.minikube/machines/minikube/tty`" you'll probably be able to open a serial tty like in [How do I see a list of all minikube clusters running in Docker on my mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53052625/how-do-i-see-a-list-of-all-minikube-clusters-running-in-docker-on-my-mac):

```
$ sudo screen /Users/youruser/.minikube/machines/minikube/tty
Welcome to minikube
minikube login: root
                         _             _
            _         _ ( )           ( )
  ___ ___  (_)  ___  (_)| |/')  _   _ | |_      __
/' _ ` _ `\| |/' _ `\| || , <  ( ) ( )| '_`\  /'__`\
| ( ) ( ) || || ( ) || || |\`\ | (_) || |_) )(  ___/
(_) (_) (_)(_)(_) (_)(_)(_) (_)`\___/'(_,__/'`\____)

# docker ps
...  <== shows a bunch of K8s containers
```

Comment: Thank you! I succeeded to find a tty and attached it!