# Gramex raises an "inotify watch limited reached" error in a Docker container

Tags: docker, inotify, gramex

We are seeing the following error when we deploy a Gramex portal in production as time passes by.

```
Inotify._raise_error()
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/watchdog/observers/inotify_c.py", line 421, in _raise_error
raise OSError(errno.ENOSPC, "inotify watch limit reached")
OSError: [Errno 28] inotify watch limit reached
```

The error does not occur immediately after we deploy. It occurs after  1 or 2 hours after deployment. After that, the portal stops working. We're restarting our docker containers when the application stops responding after 2 or 3 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Set `watch: false` under `app:` in your `gramex.yaml`.

```yaml
app:
  watch: false
```

You can increase the [inotify limit](https://learn.gramener.com/guide/watch/#inotify-limit) in the host, but [you can't set these in docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57221024/100904).

This means that if your files change, Gramex needs to be restarted. But it won't fail due to the inotify limit.