# Cannot list out stopped container using docker ps -a

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

I tried to remove a image using `docker rmi image_id` and terminal output `Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete dd85c346890b (must be forced) - image is being used by stopped container b91e905c2b8e`. Then I tried to list out the container using `docker ps -a` but it does not shown. Then I tried `docker inspect b91e905c2b8e` it does exists. And I can remove the container using `docker rm b91e905c2b8e`.

Why the container is not shown using `docker ps -a`. The container is created using `kubectl apply pod_config.yaml`. Will this affect docker?

Edited:
pod.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Pod 
metadata: 
  name: my-pod
  labels: 
    component: web
spec: 
  containers: 
    - name: client 
      image: imageB // original is imageA    
      ports: 
        - containerPort: 3000
```

Comment: Check if the pod was scheduled on the node where you are doing docker commands

Comment: You probably shouldn't manually use `docker` commands on a node managed by Kubernetes; delete the Kubernetes Pod (or its controlling Deployment/StatefulSet/Job/DaemonSet) instead.  If you're not in a purely-local environment (Docker Desktop) you typically shouldn't/can't log into the worker nodes at all.

Comment: the pod previously use the container (b91e905c2b8e), but now replaced by a new another container and is running. Can you explain what is happening?@ArghyaSadhu

Comment: Because I changed the container inside the pod from A to B, but A remains, also, its image. How can I remove them? I cannot remove the pod as the pod is still in use. @DavidMaze

Comment: If the pod is still in use, then the image is still in use, and you can't delete it.

Comment: No, actually I changed the image in the Pod, like from image A to image B in the pod yaml, so I want to remove image A and its container now? @DavidMaze

Comment: Please share more info about your k8s cluster as we don't know anything about your installation. Is it one-node cluster or does it have more nodes ? If it has more nodes, on which node are you running your docker commands ?

Comment: @mario Hi Mario, I am using Kubernetes in Docker for mac, it is single node cluster. I created the pod.yaml apply it using kubectl. Then I change the image, from imageA to imageB, and apply using kubectl again.

Comment: Do you push your images to some registry before using them ? Or maybe you build them and store them only locally ? Are you sure `Image B` isn't somehow dependent on `Image A` ? Isn't it using same layers ? If `image A` isn't used any more by any container it should be possible to remove it without any problem. If it cannot be removed, it is probably still in use.

Comment: @mario I pushed them to docker hub. They are 2 totally independent image. The message is "image is being used by stopped container b91e905c2b8e". But my question is "Why the stopped container is not shown using docker ps -a"?

Comment: Hmm... this is quite an interesting question as normally such scenario shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Where are you actually running `docker ps -a` ? On your Mac ? Or you first attach to your k8s node VM using [screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739560/how-to-access-the-vm-created-by-dockers-hyperkit/39747831#39747831) ?

Comment: Could you additionally share your **Docker for Desktop** version and **Docker CLI** version ?

Comment: @mario I run docker ps -a on my mac, not using screen. Below is the version
Docker for Desktop: 2.3.0.4
Docker Cli: 19.03.12

I am wondering is there any scope concept inside docker?

Answer (score 3):

**Quick solution:**

```
docker --host unix:///$HOME/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/docker.raw.sock ps -a
```

**Explanation:**

It seems to be an expected behavior from Docker developers point of view.
Mac version of Docker is using specific socket to connect `docker-cli` to the daemon that runs on Hyperkit VM.

It works in exactly the same way if you are using docker binary shipped with Docker.app or installed separately.

Luckily Docker-desktop for MacOS creates two kind of sockets:

A "filtered" socket ( used by default ) for the purpose of Docker-desktop application requirements, probably related to its Kubernetes implementation:

```
$HOME/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/docker.sock
```

and the unfiltered one:

```
$HOME/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/docker.raw.sock
```

To show the differences, I've reproduced your situation and got the container with ID: `b2f1fed9c793` in `Exited` state:

```
$ docker inspect b2f1fed9c793 | grep Status
            "Status": "exited",

$ docker  ps -a | grep b2f1fed9c793
# empty output
```

When I run the same command connecting to the different sockets I'm getting different results and only raw socket shows exited containers:

```
$ docker --host unix:///$HOME/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/docker.sock ps -a | grep b2f1fed9c793
# empty output

$ docker --host unix:///$HOME/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/docker.raw.sock ps -a | grep b2f1fed9c793
b2f1fed9c793        nginx                              "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   40 minutes ago      Exited (0) 39 minutes ago                            k8s_nginx_nginx3_default_2a5ed89d-ccff-4561-a320-676603d30619_4
```

Default socket gives 0 lines with Exited containers:

```
$ docker --host unix:///$HOME/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/docker.sock ps -a | grep Exited | wc -l 
       0
```

But raw socket gives 22:

```
$ docker --host unix:///$HOME/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/docker.raw.sock ps -a | grep Exited | wc -l 
      22
```

To use the raw socked by default you can create an alias:

```
$ alias docker="docker --host unix:///$HOME/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/docker.raw.sock"

$ docker  ps -a | grep Exited | wc -l 
      22
```

The solution was originally suggested by [lalyos](https://github.com/lalyos) in the [issue comment](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2446#issuecomment-614880833), but he was solving slightly different problem.