# screen docker desktop tty

Tags: docker, terminal, screen, gnu-screen, tty

I try to screen into docker desktop vm using `screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty`, which work previously. But today is said `Cannot execute "/Users/myusername/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty": Operation not permitted`. I search and found solution saying setting security and privacy of system preference which I did follow (below image). But still I got the errors, can anyone help?

[image: Add Full Disk Access]

Comment: On Mac os ventura version 13.0.1 and docker app version 4.14.0 (91374), the screen command just exits after a few seconds because the file ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

While I don't understand the reason for this issue, I experienced the same, and the following helped for me:

- Make the tty file readable:
  `chmod 400 ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty`
- Do not try to execute that file, but read its contents:
  `screen $(cat ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty)`

Not the most beautiful solution, but works form me.

Comment: Thank you. I found another solution which is similar: screen /dev/ttys000, the /dev/ttys000 is the place the tty file points to (open tty as text file).

Comment: On Mac os ventura version 13.0.1 and docker app version 4.14.0 (91374), the screen command just exits after a few seconds because the file ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the docker vm by using a privileged container and executing `nsenter` to inherit the namespaces of the host (pid 1). You are now in the docker vm.

```
$ docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host busybox nsenter -t1 -m -u -i -n
```

Related issue: [How to access the VM created by docker's HyperKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739560/how-to-access-the-vm-created-by-dockers-hyperkit/60582083#60582083)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem in recent Docker versions([Github issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4822)). I tried many ways to workaround before downgrading the Docker. Finally, Docker version stable 2.3.0.2(45183) work for me